# Custom HTML Google Form not working when i use it in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey so i'm trying to use a custom html layout for a form and sending the data through google forms to a sheet.

The project is being developed in Angular.
When i try to send the form the "submit" button does nothing, and there are no errors in the console or the debugger.

But when i copy the exact same code into a fresh html file it works with no problems. So i'm pretty sure it has something to do with Angular.

```
  <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/(personal link)/formResponse" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="entry.1676852988" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" name="entry.567673583" placeholder="email" id="">
  <button type="submit" >Submit form</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ngNoForm directive.

```
  <form ngNoForm action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/(personal link)/formResponse" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="entry.1676852988" placeholder="name">
      <input type="text" name="entry.567673583" placeholder="email" id="">
      <button type="submit" >Submit form</button>
  </form>
```